# URI online judge - 1017 - wrong answer (60%)

Tags: java

**Input**
The input file contains two integers. The first one is the spent time in the trip (in hours). The second one is the average speed during the trip (in Km/h).

**Output**
Print how many liters would be needed to do this trip, with three digits after the decimal point.

**Problem number 1017 so I take two integer in input file and three digit after decimal point in output file but getting wrong answer (60%). Here is the code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
    public static void main( String args []){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        int x,y;
        x=sc.nextInt();
        y=sc.nextInt();
        double z=(x*y)/12;
        System.out.printf("%.3f\n",z);
    }
}
```

What is the 60% wrong answer?

Comment: You're doing integer division, then converting the result to a double, instead of the other way around.

Comment: Replace the `12` with `12.0` to do double division. Alternatively you can cast one of the inputs to `double`.

Comment: So you are telling me to take all double?

Comment: No, I'm really not.  Go read the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you. Making 12 to 12.0 remove the 60% wrong answer.

Answer (score -1):

What are the constraints?
If the integers are large, maybe you should use `long` instead of `int`.
If they are larger than that, use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Unlikely to be the problem.